# Transform false in between trues

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe like the following one:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [True, True, False, True, True], "b": [True, True, False, False, True]})
df
```

I would like to be able to transform the False values in between Trues to obtain a result like this (depending on a threshold).

```py
# Threshold = 1
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [True, True, True, True, True], "b": [True, True, False, False, True]})
df
```

```py
# Threshold = 2
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [True, True, True, True, True], "b": [True, True, True, True, True]})
df
```

Any suggestions to do this apart from a for loop?

Edit: The threshold value defines how many consecutive Falses you will take into account to do the transformation.

Edit2: In the beggining and end of the array you should not consider any special case.

Comment: what happens when `threshold` changes?

Comment: I guess "Threshold" is the maximal number of consecutive `False` which you want to turn into `True`. Not sure about that; please [edit] your question to clarify. Also, what about beginning and end of the array? Anything special there?

Comment: I have edited to answer your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible simplify solution for replace `False`s groups less like `Threshold` value first filter separate groups by [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), counts by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and last compare by [`DataFrame.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) with pass to [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
Threshold = 1

m = df.cumsum().mask(df).apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts())).le(Threshold)

df = df.mask(m, True)
```

If need not replace start or ends groups by `False`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [False, False, True, False, True, False],
                   "b": [True, True, False, False, True, True]})
print (df)
       a      b
0  False   True
1  False   True
2   True  False
3  False  False
4   True   True
5  False   True

Threshold = 1

df1 = df.cumsum().mask(df)
m1 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts())).le(Threshold)
m2 = df1.ne(df1.iloc[0]) & df1.ne(df1.iloc[-1])

df = df.mask(m1 & m2, True)
print (df)
       a      b
0  False   True
1  False   True
2   True  False
3   True  False
4   True   True
5  False   True
```

Comment: This did the trick. Ty mate!!!

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to use itertools groupby to generate counts of each adjacent items group, but sadly it does include a couple of loops:

```
from itertools import groupby

def how_many_identical_elements(itter):
    return sum([[x]*x for x in [len(list(v)) for g,v in groupby(itter)]], [])

def fill_up_df(df, th):
    df = df.copy()
    for c in df.columns:
        df[f'{c}_count'] = how_many_identical_elements(df[c].values)
        df[c] = [False if x[0]==False and x[1]>th else True for x in zip(df[c], df[f'{c}_count'])]
    return df[[c for c in df.columns if 'count' not in c]]
```

then

```
fill_up_df(df, 1)
```

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | True |
| 1 | True | True |
| 2 | True | False |
| 3 | True | False |
| 4 | True | True |

```
fill_up_df(df, 2)
```

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | True |
| 1 | True | True |
| 2 | True | True |
| 3 | True | True |
| 4 | True | True |

Answer (score 0):

This code looks from -threshold -> threshold, on a column-by-column basis and or's the results together to create a masking dataframe that meets your criteria. The last line is just the logical or of your original data and the new mask as we only need to fill False values. It should be one of the faster solutions if speed is an issue.

```
threshold = 2

filling_mask = reduce(
    lambda x, y: x | y,
    (
        df.shift(-i, fill_value=True) & df.shift(i, fill_value=True) 
        for i in range(1, threshold + 1)
    )
)

df |= filling_mask
```

Threshold 1:

```
>>> df # Threshold 1
     a       b
0   True    True
1   True    True
2   True    False
3   True    False
4   True    True
```

Threshold 2:

```
>>> df # Threshold 2
     a       b
0   True    True
1   True    True
2   True    True
3   True    True
4   True    True
```